# express-session with mongo-store - Headers already sent in req.session.save() callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

im using express-session with a mongo-store.
However, in my authentication process i call req.session.save() after the user is authenticated successfully. But when i try to send a response to the client i get the message `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

When i send the response before i call req.session.save() and not inside the callback, its working.
This is what my code snippet looks like.

```
// res.json({ data: 'hello world' }); //This is working... 
       req.session.save((err) => {
           if (err) {
               console.log('Error saving session: ', err);
           } else {
               // res.json({ data: 'Hello CB' }); //Headers already sent
           }
       });
```

I also can see that the session is saved in my mongoDb.
I couldn't find anything which tells me, that req.session.save() is sending some response to the client.

Why are the headers already sent in the callback function of req.session.save() ?

Updated full Requestfunction:

```
const Create = async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.body;
    await Authenticate(code)
        .then((user) => {
            //Check if User already exists in database
            UserModel.getUser(user.id)
                .then((resDB) => {
                    if (resDB === null) {
                        console.log('User not found');
                        //User dont exists, create it
                        UserModel.createUser({
                           ...
                        })
                            .then((is_saved) => {
                                if (is_saved) {
                                    res.json(user);
                                    res.end();
                                }
                            })
                    } else {

                        req.session.regenerate((err) => {
                            req.session.value = "somevalue";    
                        });

                        req.session.save((err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Error saving session: ', err);
                            } else {
                            // res.json({ cookie: req.session });
                            res.json({ data: 'Hello from CB' });
                            res.end();
                        }
                    });
                        
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('User Create or Login error: ', err);
                    res.end();
                })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Authentication error', err);
            res.end();
        });
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using too many nested .then().catch() , i tried your code and it worked fine for me ,so I suggest you change it to a trycatch block with error throwing in case of errors I can share the code for you if you want

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing  `async and await`. Can you share complete method code?

```
 const saveInSession =  async (req, res, next) => {
    const getData = await req.body; //just an example
    req.session.save((err) => {
           if (err) {
               console.log('Error saving session: ', err);
           } else {
               // res.json({ data: 'Hello CB' }); //Headers already sent
           }
       });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, but im already using async and wait. I updated my question with full request function. Do you still see any async/await problems?